# Display number in stationing format in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling

I have a shapefile made of points. One of its field is `PROGR_TRAC`, which represents the station of the feature along a path.

For example I have in the field `PROGR_TRAC` the value `21519.70`. This value is not a string but a decimal number.

I have created a code that display this value in the label in a format 21+519

```
to_int(round(floor("PROGR_TRAC"/1000))) || '+' ||  lpad(floor(to_real( right(to_string(( "PROGR_TRAC") ),6))),3,0)
```

The problem is that when the last digit is "0", the string conversion truncate the "0" at the end.

So instead of returning 21+519 it returns 21+151.

Therefore, I need *something* which reads what is after the "." characters and counts if the lengths is 1 or 2 and if the length is 1 it should append a 0 at the end of the string.

Does anyone have any idea how to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work with numbers directly: `floor` it first to get rid of the decimal, then keep the 3 rightmost chars

```
right(floor("PROGR_TRAC"),3)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! really straight forword!! i was convinced i had to work with strings!